# Can't Get Java Program to List Files In A Specified Directory

Tags: java, serialization, directory, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a program (for school homework) that will take a command-line argument to specify a directory, and for the time being, just print out the files in the directory.  I have literally been looking at various answers and trying things out for hours now, and just have no idea what to do.  Below, you will find my current code.  when I open a CMD, and type `java DirectoryFiles c:\` .

I get `Error, could not find or load main class DirectoryFiles`.  I just used `c:\` to see if I could get any directory to print out.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectoryFiles
{

    /**
     * Gets command line argument for directory to be used in program.
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {

        String path = args[0];
        File dir = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dir);
        if ((dir).isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();

            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you change directory in cmd to the directory of your project/source before typing your command?

Comment: 1) `fis` is unnecessary 2) Parens around `dir` aren't needed 3) Calling `println` on an array will only show `[Ljava.io.File;@memaddr`, not the elements themselves. 4) How are you compiling/running your code? The code itself should (almost) work; it's not the problem here.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response!  I have not changed directory to the directory of my source...going to try that now.  I am compiling code using eclipse.

Comment: @HTNW thanks for the tips!  I removed fis, removed the parenthesis from dir, and iterated through each index in the array.  I also ran the .class file in the CMD instead of the .java file, and now, it works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have only the **source** file (you didn't compile it).

Remember that:

- Java is not an interpreter of a source file.
- `java` command attempts to run an existing java **class**.

So you must start from compiling the source code into a Java class.
Then you can run it with `java` command.

Comment: Oh my god! I have been trying to run the DirectoryFiles.java file. When I moved the DirectoryFiles.class file to the c:\ and then typed in c:\> java DirectoryFiles f:\ it ran!!!!!! So, correct me if I am wrong, but what I have learned is that you can run .java files in eclipse or netBeans, or whatever, but when you want to run a program from the CMD, you need to use the .class file from your java program. Is this correct?

Comment: *Runining .java files from Eclipse* is a "conceptual shortcut".
Actually, Eclipse first compiles your source file (and all others in case of more complex project). Only after that it runs the program.
So Eclipse relieves you from manual repeatable operations.
But when you attempt to repeat the whole procedure from the command line, there is no "secret helper" which could do these operations instead of you. You must then do them on your own.